# What is the proper setting so when my birthday comes, my friends will get a notification?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

Facebook notifies friends when they have a birthday. For example, one of my friends had a birthday today and I got a notification that said `Today is <<name's>> birthday`. How do I set it up so that my friends get the notification?

I have my birthday set to `Friends of Friends` but my birth year set to `Only Me`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting your birthday to "Friends of Friends" means that when your friends and their friends visit the About page on your profile, they will see the month and day of your birthday.  In addition, the fact that your friends can see your birthday means that Facebook will notify all of your friends about your birthday.  You don't need to change anything - your account is already set up for your friends to receive the birthday notification.  If you don't want birthday notifications to go out to your friends, then you would have to set your birthday to "Only Me".

Setting your birth year to "Only Me" will not affect the birthday notification that goes out to your friends.  It will only hide your birth year when people visit the About page on your profile.

Comment: Yeah but I have a friend who's birthday is listed on the top right corner of my Facebook homepage but I didn't get her notification even though her visibility is visible to me.

Comment: The fact that Facebook tells you about your friend's birthday in the upper right corner means that you should be able to receive a notification.  Do you mean an email notification?  Maybe you have your email notifications turned off.  You can go to Settings > Notifications > Email > Upcoming birthdays, and click "Turn On".

Comment: I'm not talking about email notification. I'm talking about the Facebook "Globe" icon notification when you login. Yeah I also receive the email notification for upcoming birthdays but I'm talking about the birthday for the "Today". It says "Today is <<name's>> birthday".

Comment: When you click on that Globe icon, there is a "Settings" link.  Click on that, and it takes you to the Notifications Settings page.  On that page, it says "You'll see every notification on Facebook, but you can turn off notifications about specific posts as you view them."  So those birthday notifications should happen automatically.  But I think the Facebook notification system is a little flaky, because occasionally someone will like one of my updates or comment on one of my updates and I don't see the notification show up on the globe.